# Trying to mix 2 blockchain platforms

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ethereum, hyperledger, corda, hyperledger-sawtooth

Wanted to know if we mix 2 or more blockchain platforms with one another like Hyperledger Fabric, Etherium, Quorum or R3 Corda? So can I mix them to  achieve a model which is good for both public as well as private blockchain network.

Comment: This question is a little too broad.  What type(s) of use case(s) are you going after here?  There are projects like Hyperledger Quilt (which is an implementation of the Interledger Protocol) which aim to aid in these types of use cases, but it really depends on what you are trying to do, your assumptions, etc

Comment: I really don't have any use case on my mind. I was just curious if we can combine any two Blockchain platform because i read hyperledger fabric, r3 corda are two private permission network and etherium provide permission less public and private platform so, that is why i got question on my mind.

Comment: This is really too broad a question for SO. You might use a mailing list such as hyperledger-technical-discuss@lists.hyperledger.org for a question such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain technologies are standalone and are usually not compatible with each other.

An exception exists with Ethereum Virtual Machine, which is implemented in Hyperledger Burrow and is supported with Seth in Hyperledger Sawtooth (Seth = Sawtooth Ethereum).

You can also use Hyperledger Quilt, which is designed to communicate between various blockchain technologies.